# EF Core removerange items not removed on transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

Here's my prblem

```
using (var db = new CassaContext()) {        
      var DbSet = db.GetByName(item.Name);
      DbSet.RemoveRange(DbSet);

      for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
      {
           JObject jitem = data[i] as JObject;
           var dbobj = vm.Db.JsonToObject(jitem);             
           DbSet.Add(dbobj);
       }

       db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If i will add db.SaveChanges() after the RemoveRange() istruction, everything is fine, but, without that, i have the error

> The instance of entity type 'Users' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance of this type with the same key is already being
>   tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique
>   temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key
>   property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are
>   explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

I would like to avoid saving after the removerange, because i won't have empty tables if the transaction fails.

How can i solve this? Thanks in advance!
If you need more just ask!

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: *another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked*. You add an entity that you just removed.

Comment: And what would be the problem? It was working on EF7 as well. I suppose, i can insert and remove entities in a database.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this error, but you could try using an explicit transaction:

```
using (var db = new CassaContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var DbSet = db.GetByName(item.Name);
    DbSet.RemoveRange(DbSet);
    db.SaveChanges();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        JObject jitem = data[i] as JObject;
        var dbobj = vm.Db.JsonToObject(jitem);             
        DbSet.Add(dbobj);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the job! It seems to work as well, even on transaction error. I didn't think to use an explicit transaction because it was working on EF7. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, in **Entityframework** you have to write **savechange** after each **database** execution. Hence, your function should look like this

```
using (var db = new CassaContext()) {        
  var DbSet = db.GetByName(item.Name);
  DbSet.RemoveRange(DbSet);
  db.SaveChanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
  {
       JObject jitem = data[i] as JObject;
       var dbobj = vm.Db.JsonToObject(jitem);             
       DbSet.Add(dbobj);
       db.SaveChanges();
   }

   db.SaveChanges();
```

}