# Removing range using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I´m getting an error when using RemoveRange to bulk delete data, in my unit tests, using InMemoryDatabase.

Here is the code:

```
public void DeletePatient(Paciente patient)
{
    var schedules = dbContext.Schedules.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.PatientId == patient.Id).ToList();
    dbContext.Schedules.RemoveRange(schedules);

    dbContext.Patients.Remove(patient);
}
```

This throws this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Schedule' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

But, if I perform a foreach and reload each entity, it works:

```
foreach(var item in schedules)
{
    var h = dbContext.Schedules.Find(item.Id);
    dbContext.Remove(h);
}
```

The same foreach, using the item directly gives same error:

```
foreach(var item in schedules)
{
    dbContext.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core removerange items not removed on transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643184/ef-core-removerange-items-not-removed-on-transaction)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I´m using InMemoryDatabase, that does not have transactions.

Comment: Why did you use `AsNoTracking()` if you intend to make changes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I´m new to EF. I though that tracking was needed only for updates.

Comment: That's exactly what you are doing. Updating the database. `AsNoTracking()` is used only when you *don't* want to make any modification, just load some entities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the AsNoTracking clause.  I haven't tested it but my guess is this is causing EF to re-read the entities from the database and not finding the ones already in the context.  Without the clause it should find the actual entities in the context to be removed.

Comment: No need to test. Tracking is used to enable changes and keep track of modifications performed by the user. Without tracking, when `SaveChanges` is called EF sees only  a list of entities that it has to save to the database